# When will the site leave private beta status

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I see some questions like [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15064/how-can-i-provide-my-text-book-to-my-students-in-e-book-format) (academia.SE) where someone should be directed here but they won't be able to see anything until we leave private beta.

Is it set when the site will become open to the public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have been in public beta since at least Tue December 24 at 17:46.  I posted a comment in chat when I noticed it.

Comment: actually I received the mail stating that ebooks.SE is on public beta just half an hour ago :-)

Comment: @mau I seem to have got the email about the same time as you.  I guess the person who does the actual promotion of the site had a different holiday schedule then the person who sends the emails.

Comment: I thought it was automatic... but evidently this is not the case!